# Custom Django Usermodel

Tags: python, django, authentication, model, customization

i just tried to create my own custom Django user model but it fails if i try to create a new user through the frontend:

> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/ Django
>   Version:  2.1b1 Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value: 
>   'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'

First i created a new Django App `"accounts"`
then i've added the following to models.py of the accounts app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
) 

#User Model Manager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Error: The User you want to create must have an username, try again')

        user = self.model(
            user=self.normalize_username(username),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='username',
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that's built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Username & Password are required by default.

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username address
        return self.user

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username address
        return self.user
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.user

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """Does the user have a specific permission?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        """Is the user a admin member?"""
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        """Is the user active?"""
        return self.active
```

model.py of my actual blog app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from smartfields import fields
from smartfields.dependencies import FileDependency
from smartfields.processors import ImageProcessor

# Categorys of Post Model

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    cover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='categorycovers/', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 350, 'max_height': 350}))
    ])
    icon = fields.ImageField(upload_to='categoryicons/', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 16, 'max_height': 16}))
    ])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    postattachment = fields.FileField(upload_to='postattachment/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True ,null=True)
    postcover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='postcover/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 200, 'max_height': 200}))
    ])
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#Comment(s) of Post Model
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

After that i jumpt back to settings.py and added the custom user model to my acctual blog application:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

and i also added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'accounts',
...   
]
```

I dont want any email address for my users. i simply and only want them to be authenticated through the username...

Any hints? Thanks :)

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes, and then i get the error: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
see pastebin: https://pastebin.com/K1F8HhA7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User`, Django complained about unknown field `username` in your Custom `User` model, you don't have `username` field but you stated `USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'`.

**The simple solution is to rename your `user` field to `username`**.

If you need that name for some reason (`user`) you should change `username` to `user` in `get_full_name` and `get_short_name` and don't forget also in `create_user` (`user = self.model(user =self.normalize_username(username),)`)

**Try:**

**Reaname all created users to some other name (ex. my_user) because you have tow varibales with the same name (the USERNAME_FIELD and the user created)**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


#User Model Manager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, user, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not user:
            raise ValueError('Error: The User you want to create must have an username, try again')

        my_user = self.model(
            user=self.normalize_username(user),
        )

        my_user.set_password(password)
        my_user.save(using=self._db)
        return my_user

    def create_staffuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given username and password.
        """
        my_user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        my_user.staff = True
        my_user.save(using=self._db)
        return my_user

    def create_superuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        my_user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        my_user.staff = True
        my_user.admin = True
        my_user.save(using=self._db)
        return my_user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='username',
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that's built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Username & Password are required by default.

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username address
        return self.user

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username address
        return self.user    
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.user

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """Does the user have a specific permission?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        """Is the user a admin member?"""
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        """Is the user active?"""
        return self.active
```

Your `settings.py` file looks great.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Seems to did the job but now i get:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "quickblog_post" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "quickblog_post"

Comment: @Venom update the question with the full traceback error.

Comment: I will close this question for now an di will open a new one with the new error. Thanks everybody :D

Answer (score 1):

Django `AbstractBaseUser` class has no field `username`

in your declaration you declare a username field and named it `user`

but `USERNAME_FIELD` is `username`

change your model like this

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='username',
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Username & Password are required by default.

    ...
```

also you can rename user field in User model to username and problem solved.